# Web-apps recording/replay software

Tags: windows, web-development, web-browser, automation, software-testing

I have been attempting to implement a system with my company that will record data sent over the web and make it possible to make edits to the information and replay it. It will be fine if the software uses GUI based or code based for initial set up. I would prefer GUI based to some sort for long term usage. I'd prefer free/open sourced software with (hopefully) a scripting language that I can utilize to make the customization I need (If it's open source I can always just edit the source). I would need this to be client side. I have scripts for server side already that does basic verification.

Requirements:

- Ability to replay actions performed in browser
- Ability to be used for multiple websites
- Windows based
- Ability to save and transfer script from one machine to another
- Ability to easily update/maintain after initial set up

Big pluses:

- Embedded Scripting Language
- GUI
- Utilizes browser(s)
- If I can manipulate the data within the recording (Extract it, change it, store it how I want to, etc etc)

I have looked into:

- [HP LoadRunner](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/loadrunner-load-testing/index.html) (Automated Load Tester for several protocols): Too expensive, too code dependent. Not a suitable/viable option at all.
- [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org) (Automated Web Driver): too code dependent, possible solution though.
- Customized Browser Extension(s): Possible solution, I am not sure how much time I have to perform these duties though
- [Java Embedded Browsers](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html): Company was not satisfied with this solution, they'd prefer a solution that uses a 'native' browser. Could not convince them that it uses a native browser wrapped in Java.

Background: I am in Software Testing, Web Apps in particular. I have a system for my API that uses a property file system that runs the interface for the API. I would like the ability to use that for both the API and the front end website. I have started working on developing such a system but was curious if anyone was aware of anything that would require minimal coding for maintenance work.

Creative answers are also acceptable.

Comment: Have you looked at Fiddler? http://www.telerik.com/fiddler I haven't posted it as a full answer since I haven't used it myself and don't know if it allows replaying actions, but it describes itself as "The free web debugging proxy 
for any browser, system or platform"

Comment: Take a look at Scripted Selenium: https://bitbucket.org/djarvis/scripted-selenium/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at [Project SIKULI](http://www.sikuli.org/) "Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components." - scriptable, browser agnostic, open source, GUI-based, cross platform.